# Should I include non-Python files in my package?

Tags: python, python-packaging

I have a package in which its version is in a file `VERSION.txt`,in `setup.py` I have the following:

```py
with open('VERSION.txt', 'r') as v:
    version = v.read().strip()

 setuptools.setup(
     ...
     version=version,
     ...
 )
```

If I install and try to run it I get `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'VERSION.txt'`, obviously because I am not including the `VERSION.txt` in my package, but I don't think I should.
The way this code is working would need to add `include_package_data=True` and creating a `MANIFEST.in`.

Is there any other approach where I could, in a development environment, still have this `VERSION.txt` but not sending it inside my package?

Comment: Fetch it from the internet maybe? Or does `pip` maintain a version index that you could query to get your program's version from when you last touched it with `pip`?

Comment: Your package build script should generate `setup.py` from a template and `VERSION.txt`, so that the packaged `setup.py` has a hard-coded version.

Comment: @chepner I thought about writing this script but looks like overhead compared to inserting the version file in the package.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy There's a setup.py file that needs the hardcoded string representing the version before you try to build the package. Not sure fetching from the internet would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version information is usually included in a package, since it can be very useful for a piece of software to know and communicate its own version. A good source to check out how best to do it are project templates, for example [the list of official cookiecutters](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter#a-pantry-full-of-cookiecutters).

---

To give my personal favorite, I like putting a variable `__version__ = '0.1.2'` into my topmost `__init__.py` file:

```
mypackage
├───src
│   └───mypackage
│       └───__init__.py  # only content here is the version string
└───setup.py
```

Which I can then import in the `setup.py` ...

```py
from src.mypackage import __version__

setuptools.setup(
    ...
    version=__version__,
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    packages=find_packages(where='src'),
    ...
)
```

... and also easily access when my package is installed

```py
>>> from mypackage import __version__
>>> print(__version__)
0.1.2
```